# How to access jobparameter from ItemReader class of Spring batch job in spring boot web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am launching a spring batch Job from my controller. I need to access the job parameter `fileName` from configured custom `ItemReader` via java based configuration.But I always gets the fileName as null from my ItemReader. Please help.
I am launching like this because I have to change ItemReader file according to the user request.

My Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class SimpleController {


@Autowired
Step step;

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory steps;

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;

@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void StartJob() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    JobParameter param = new JobParameter("ValueBeingSetFromRequestHeader");
    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
    map.put("fileName",param);
    SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob("test");
    job.addStep(step);
    System.out.println(jobRepository);
    job.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

    System.out.println( jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(job.getName(), new JobParameters(map)));

    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(map));

}
```

}

And my Job step configuration class is

```
public class ProducerBatchJobConfigurer {


private String fileName;

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

@Bean
public ItemReader reader() {
    System.out.println(fileName);
    if (fileName == null)
        return new DummyReader();
    FlatFileItemReader faltFileReader =  new FlatFileItemReader();

    faltFileReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName)));
    faltFileReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName)));
    DefaultLineMapper<KafkaMessage> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<KafkaMessage>();
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer());
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new CSVFieldMapper());
    faltFileReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    return faltFileReader;
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor processor() {
   return new CustomItemProcessor();

}

@Bean
public ItemWriter writer() {
    return new KafkaWriter();
}



@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                  ItemReader reader, ItemWriter writer,
                  ItemProcessor processor) {
    System.out.println("ddddddddddddddd");
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .chunk(10).reader(reader)
            .processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
}
@Bean
public StepScope stepScope() {
    final StepScope stepScope = new StepScope();
    stepScope.setAutoProxy(true);
    return stepScope;
}
@Bean
public JobScope jobScope(){
    return new JobScope();
}
}
```

Comment: ProducerBatchJobConfigurer  is not a bean by it self, i would use the @value on the ItemReader Beandefinition reader(@Value ....)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. Now with your change fileName gets populated. But cannot run the job.Step fails with the  following error.


```org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read.
 at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:195) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]```

Comment: I had to put @Scope("job") also on top of reader else it was giving error ```Property or field 'jobParameters' cannot be found ```

But Unfortunately cannot run the job . Step fails with the  following error.
```org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read.
 at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:195) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]```

Comment: please try it with ItemStreamReader or concrete FlatFileItemReader as Beantype, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847661/spring-batch-org-springframework-batch-item-readernotopenexception-reader-must, if it works you or me can post it as solution

Comment: @MichaelPralow : Thanks. It is working. Please go ahead and post it as solution. Please explain a bit more if possible. :)

Comment: @MichaelPralow : If possible please check one of my another issue  Asked here [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791180/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Bean
public ItemReader reader() {
 ...
}
```

should be changed to

```
@Bean
public ItemStreamReader reader() {
 ...
}
```

or even more specific

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader reader() {
 ...
}
```

Step definition should be changed as well to

```
@Bean
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                  ItemStreamReader reader, ItemWriter writer,
                  ItemProcessor processor) {

}
```

Why is that necessary?

If an itemReader implements the [ItemStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html) Interface (or [ItemStreamReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStreamReader.html)) Spring will treat it as a such.

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#delegatePatternAndRegistering

> A reader, writer, or processor that is directly wired into the Step
>   will be registered automatically if it implements ItemStream or a
>   StepListener interface.

that means spring will call the open, update and close methods

similar problem at [Spring Batch: org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847661/spring-batch-org-springframework-batch-item-readernotopenexception-reader-must)

Answer (score -1):

Use `@Value("#{jobParameters[fileName]}")` instead of `@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above. But Not working. :(